# Baby Rudin Example 1.1 and proof by contradiction?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have a question about example 1.1 on Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin. This is the example that starts with $p^2=2$ and tries to prove no rational number $p$ exists that satisfies the equation. He tries to prove this by contradiction by assuming there is a $p$ such that $p=m/n$. I didn't get why $m$ and $n$ can't be both even. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If they were both even, we could take out a factor of $2$ from both.

Comment: You can assume that $m$ and $n$ are coprime (i.e., don't share any factors) by dividing the common factors out if necessary.

Comment: Hi @AnginaSeng, tks! I think that I got it. If they were coprimes, how can I proceed with the proof?

Comment: If they are coprime, one (or both) are odd. @MarceloRM

Comment: Thanks @AnginaSeng and KentaS.